# .htaccess - Block all unless matching IP except for one file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` file that forbids access to all files in a directory unless the IP of the visitor is white-listed:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# OFFICE 1 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123

# OFFICE 2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.213\.123\.213

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

</IfModule>
```

How do also add access to one specific file (`myfile.txt`)?

Comment: Not easily - the site is installed using CPanel and I don't fancy playing around with that minefield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do this. I can specify the file I want to be allowed through at the top of the rules, and then make that the Last statement if true:

```
RewriteRule ^myfile.txt$ - [L]
```

Complete example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^myfile.txt$ - [L]

# OFFICE 1 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123

# OFFICE 2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.213\.123\.213

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your requirement. You can make a small correction in your 1st rule: `RewriteRule ^myfile\.txt$ - [L,NC]` or just convert that rule to a condition i.e. `RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfile\.txt$ [NC]`